# Rails Inconsistently Serving Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline, unicorn

I have a Rails 4.1.4 application being served with Unicorn and Nginx. I set it up using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) guide. The problem I am having is that when I load the webpage the assets don't load about 40% of the time.

When the assets **don't** load, chrome's console shows that the request went to:

`http://10.1.1.150:8080/stylesheets/application.css`

which gives a 404, and when they **do** load it shows:

`http://10.1.1.150:8080/assets/application-acc2ff90682d6f0f7a3ba59e8bffcc1e.css`

What would cause the path to the assets to change like that?

**Edit:**

Here is my layout code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TicketTracker</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
      <%= link_to "Ticket Tracker", tickets_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Open Tickets", tickets_path(status: "open"), class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <%= link_to "Closed Tickets", tickets_path(status: "closed"), class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Logout (#{current_user.email})", :logout, method: :post, class: "pull-right" %>
      <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, class: "pull-right" %>
      <% end %>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <%= bootstrap_flash %>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your layout code

Comment: If this isn't running in `production` mode you may have issues like this.

Comment: It is in production mode. I can add the logs shown in logs/production.rb if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and then recompiling and then restarting the server fixed it.